# Using inheritance or templates for special case behavior

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have two classes `A` and `B`, which are subclasses of an `Operator` class which has an `operate()` method.

```
class Operator {
     // ...
     virtual void operate() = 0;
};
class A : public Operator {
     void operate() { /* ... */ }
};
class B : public Operator {
     void operate() { /* ... */ }
};
```

I want to create a class that performs two operations, but has a unique behavior when both operations are of type `B`. Something like

```
 class DoubleOperator {
     Operator* operator1;
     Operator* operator2;
     // ...

 public:
     void operateTwice() {
         if (/* operator1 and operator2 are of type B */) {
             // Do a special combined operation.
         } else { // Otherwise, do the operations separately.
             operator1->operate();
             operator2->operate();
         }
     }
};
```

Is there a simple way to use inheritance or templates to produce this behavior?

Comment: Presumably `DoubleOperator` has pointers or references to `Operator` objects - it can't have members of an abstract type.

Comment: That's right. I'll update that.

Comment: Do you perhaps wants [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)?

Comment: @kfsone That had been my first thought too, but it's quite invasive in this case and it could be a suboptimal solution. It's also more time-consuming to maintain if the hierarchy changes indeed.

Comment: What's wrong with just doing a `dynamic_cast` twice?

Comment: @Barry As long as the real problem is _checks if they are both of type `B`_ it looks as the easiest solution indeed. Initially I misunderstood the problem and read _both of the same (unspecified) type_: in this case a _dynamic_cast_ would be tricky to use. It mostly depends on the actual problem, the OP is the only one that can say that.

Answer (score 1):

You can *type-erase* the operators with an intermediate function and a bit of *SFINAE*.
It follows a minimal, working example (C++14, easily convertible to C++11):

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

class Operator {
     // ...
     virtual void operate() = 0;
};
class A : public Operator {
     void operate() { /* ... */ }
};
class B : public Operator {
     void operate() { /* ... */ }
};

class DoubleOperator {
    template<typename T, typename U>
    static
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,U>::value>
    proto() {
        std::cout << "same" << std::endl;
        // Do a special combined operation.
    }

    template<typename T, typename U>
    static
    std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same<T,U>::value>
    proto() {
        std::cout << "not same" << std::endl;
        // Otherwise, do the operations separately.
    }

     Operator* operator1;
     Operator* operator2;
     void(*internalOperatorTwice)(void);
     // ...

public:
    template<typename T, typename U>
    DoubleOperator(T *t, U *u): operator1{t}, operator2{u} {
        internalOperatorTwice = &proto<T, U>;
    }

     void operateTwice() {
         internalOperatorTwice();
     }
};

int main() {
    A a1;
    A a2;
    B b;
    DoubleOperator do1{&a1, &a2};
    do1.operateTwice();
    DoubleOperator do2{&a1, &b};
    do2.operateTwice();
}
```

You can extend/modify the `proto` accordingly with your needs.

**EDIT**

I've read once more the question and here is a refinement of the answer.
What I said above is still valid. Anyway, if you want to do *something different* only when you have two instances of `B`, you can use the following `proto` functions:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
static
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,B>::value and std::is_same<U,B>::value>
proto() {
    std::cout << "same" << std::endl;
    // Do a special combined operation.
}

template<typename T, typename U>
static
std::enable_if_t<not (std::is_same<T,B>::value and std::is_same<U,B>::value)>
proto() {
    std::cout << "not same" << std::endl;
    // Otherwise, do the operations separately.
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to check if T and U are both of a specific type, not just the same type?

Comment: @ech Updated the answer. Now it replies exactly to the question.

Comment: Well, a comment made by the downvoters would help optimizing the answer... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whar you're asking is:

**How to check if `Derived` is *dynamic type* of variable with *static type* `Base&`
?**

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void f(){}
};
struct Derived:Base{};

Derived d;
Base& b = d;

if (typeid(b)==typeid(Derived))
{
    //...
}
```

Explanation:

5.2.8/2 says:

> When typeid is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a **polymorphic class type** (10.3), the result refers
>   to a std::type_info object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that is, **the dynamic
>   type**) to which the glvalue refers. [...].

So, we made `Base` polymorphic class type by adding `virtual` function to it and the we applied `typeid`, which then returned dynamic type.